# C# ChartArea PlotArea TickLabels Ratio

Tags: c#, .net, excel, charts, msdn

I am using Excel Interop Charts to plot graphs dynamically. The TickLabels are not displayed fully, I have to manually resize the plotarea to make the TickLabels visible. I tried specifying the Height of PlotArea but it failed.
Is there any programmable property to specify the ratio of PlotArea and TickLabels area?
Regards,
Vikron

Answer (score 0):

Found, you need to Select the PlotArea and then modify the height/width

```
chart.PlotArea.Select();
chart.PlotArea.Height = 300;
```